# How to show <tbody> in a grid view?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

how can I show  Elements in a grid view (horizontal, 3-4 elements per row) with enough space between the elements?
I tried it with `margin` but it did not work.

My ..html.erb:

```
<h1> Einträge </h1>

<table>
<% @listings.each do |listing| %>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th><%= listing.title %></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><%= listing.text %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><%= listing.zipcode %>, <%= listing.city %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><%= link_to 'Anzeigen', listing_path(listing) %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Bearbeiten', edit_listing_path(listing) %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Löschen', listing_path(listing),
                                method: :delete,
                                data: { confirm: 'Sind Sie sicher?'} %></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<% end %>
 </table>

  <%= link_to 'Neuer Eintrag', new_listing_path %>
```

My css-file:

```
...
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody {
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: You want to add space beetwen the cells?

Comment: yes. and show the elements in a "grid view". 3-4 elements per row. I have used <tbody> to group my stuff in elements

Comment: There are other stuff you can do to the grid, but try first with the sugestion in my answer, and if that is not want you need, let me know, to see if I can help you.

Comment: thank you for your help. It was not not that what I want. But I solved it on a other way

Comment: Glad that you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the `<td>` tag `border` and/or `padding`, try something like this:

```
td {
  border: 30px solid #040;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

And adjust the values until you have the desire result.

Note: with the developer tools you can inspect the element, and you will get a image like this with the values of `border` and `padding` of all the elements in your view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that problem, but i have a little problem: 
I get 3 Elements per row(I wanted it so) in the second row I am getting 1 Element and in the third line I get 3 Elements again.

Where can the problem be? I want in every row 3 Elements

My solution:

..html.erb:

```
<table>
  <% $c = 0 %>
  <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
  <% puts $c %>
  <% if $c == 3 %>
<tr>
  <td>
      <strong><%= listing.title %></strong>
    </br>
      <%= listing.text %>
    </br>
      <%= listing.zipcode %>, <%= listing.city %>
    </br>
      <%= link_to 'Anzeigen', listing_path(listing) %>
      <%= link_to 'Bearbeiten', edit_listing_path(listing) %>
      <%= link_to 'Löschen', listing_path(listing),
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Sind Sie sicher?'} %> </td>
    <% $c = 0 %>
  </tr>
  <% else %>
<% $c += 1 %>
<td>
    <strong><%= listing.title %></strong>
  </br>
    <%= listing.text %>
  </br>
    <%= listing.zipcode %>, <%= listing.city %>
  </br>
    <%= link_to 'Anzeigen', listing_path(listing) %>
    <%= link_to 'Bearbeiten', edit_listing_path(listing) %>
    <%= link_to 'Löschen', listing_path(listing),
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Sind Sie sicher?'} %> </td>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</table>
```

css-file:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 15px;
}

td {
border: 3px solid black;
}
```